# bash function to handle space(s) from command line argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, whitespace

Always typing `c d..` or `c d ..` to move up one dir.

Placed  function below in my .bash_profile, but only the first character before the white space  -"c" is being interpreted instead of the entire set of arguments (`c d..`),
- which I think should be only two. 
                                                                           Throwing an error

```
bash: c: - command not found
```

on bash 4.2.46.

Would like to resolve this as interpreting arguments with space(s) on the command line has more potential usefulness down the road.

Function:

```
changedir() {  
    if [[  $@ = "c d.." ]]; then  
        command cd ..  
    else  
if [[  $@ = "c d.." ]]; then  
        command cd ..  
    fi   
fi   
}
```

Also, which would be better to take an entire string of arguments - including spaces:  `$*`  or  `$@`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that function is called `changedir`, so it will only run if the shell is given the command `changedir [whatever]`. Not every time you run any command. You could abuse the `DEBUG` trap to run a function for each and every command line you enter, but we don't need that here.

Instead, just make a function called `c`, which runs `cd ..` when given the arguments `d..`, or `d` and `..`:

```
c() {
    if [[ $1 = 'd..' ]] ||
       [[ $1 = 'd' && $2 = '..' ]]; then
        command cd -- ..
    else
        echo "Invalid arguments to 'c'! Only 'c d..' and 'c d ..' are supported." >&2
    fi 
}
```

Or, you could use `shopt -s autocd` in Bash, which would make the shell go to a directory when just the directory name is given. So, `foobar` would do the same as `cd foobar` (unless a command `foobar` exists), and just `..` would go up a directory.

Comment: LOVE the shopt -s autocd!!!!   That's what I'm looking for. Now ".." goes up one dir.  I will have to discipline myself to never type "cd.." again.   Reluctant to name the function "c" as that is already aliased to "clear".   Thanx.

Comment: @jumboshrimps, weell, you could have the same function do `clear`, too if given no arguments. `if [[ $# = 0 ]]; then ...`